# Add file extension to extension-less file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add an extension to a file that is selected in an `OpenFileDialog` in my C# app.  I'm having difficulty with files that don't already have an extension.

While I haven't tested the following method on files *with* an extension, I know that it doesn't work for files *without* an extension (which is really what I want to work with here).

```
string tPath = videoPath + videoName;
string tPath2 = Path.ChangeExtension(tPath, ".yuv");
```

`tPath2` will reflect to header change, but it seems not to affect the file itself, only the string returned by the `ChangeExtension` method.  I'd just go ahead and copy the file into a new one with the appropriate name and extension, but we're talking about *huge*, uncompressed HD video files.  Is there a way to utilize `tPath2` with a `File` or `FileInfo` object that I'm missing?

I appreciate any assistance that anyone can give me here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To carry out your rename without having to make a copy, add this line at the end:

```
System.IO.File.Move(tPath, tPath2);
```

(`File.Move(src, dst)` does the same thing that `FileInfo.MoveTo(dst)` does)

For your problem of files without an extension, try this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(tPath)){
  tPath += ".yuv";
}
```

Comment: This works quite well also.  Saves me having to create a FileInfo instance as well.

Comment: Glad to help some; the FileInfo/File and DirectoryInfo/Directory classes have lots of duplicated functionality like that, so that they can work efficiently for when you have many operations to perform on the same instance (using the instance classes), or just a single operation (using the static classes). It's quite helpful, imo!

Comment: @Rich: Not that it's terribly important, but I'm curious why this is marked as the answer when I posted the same solution several minutes earlier.

Comment: I was thinking of that myself, @Adam; my only guess is that I also answered the question about the case of a file without an extension at all (which was actually the title of the question) I +1'd your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Andrew: `Path.ChangeExtension` will work on paths both with and without an extension, and it's generally preferable to use the `Path` class rather than string manipulations.

Comment: @Adam: I really thought it would myself, too; but the OP says in his post that it doesn't. Though now that I think of it, the reason it doesn't work may be because of the OTHER question that you and I both answered! :S

Answer (score 16):

The `Path` class just allows you to perform manipulations on a file *path* (meaning the `string`) at a high level, not a file itself.

You'll need to use `File.Move` in order to rename a file (including just adding an extension).

```
string tPath = videoPath + videoName;
string tPath2 = Path.ChangeExtension(tPath, ".yuv");

File.Move(tPath, tPath2); //effectively changes the extension
```

Answer (score 4):

You're just changing the file name so why don't you just do "mypath" + ".ext"?

There's nothing about the file extension change that needs to change the contents of the file, it just tells the OS what to do with it.

Comment: That's true, but I don't need to work with the string; I need to have the OS change the extension of the file.  I might be missing something you're saying though... Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: I suppose what I meant is that the Path class just provides a bunch  of utility methods for string manipulation of paths. If you actually want to change the path of the actual file, you need to use the File class, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually call [FileInfo.MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto.aspx) to rename the file.  A file rename, on the same physical drive, is usually a fast operation, so it doesn't really matter that the file is huge.